# textarea вылезает за пределы контейнера, как исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

textarea вылезает за пределы контейнера, box-sizing прописал, все равно не работает, как исправить?

```css
.contact__form-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contact__form-left {
  flex-basis: 455px;
}

.contact__form-right {
  flex-basis: 455px;
}

.contact__form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #999;
}

.contact__form p:nth-child(3) input {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contact__form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" name="contactForm" class="contact__form">
  <div class="contact__form-wrap">
    <div class="contact__form-left">
      <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="your Name *"></p>
      <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your e-mail *"></p>
      <p><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact__form-right">
      <textarea name="text" id="contactText" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your message *"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="contact__btn-wrap">
    <button type="submit" class="contact__btn btn">Send Message</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: инпуты тоже вылезают

Answer (score 0):

Сначала ересь написал. Сейчас увидел.
Попробуйте убрать `margin-left` из textarea

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось, я убрал margin-left из textarea и добавил тот же марджин блоку обертке, в котором и находится textarea

Answer (score 0):

А какой именно box-sizing Вы писали, что он Вам не помог? Вот я задал box-sizing: border-box + убрал margin-left, и всё ок:

```css
.contact__form-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.contact__form-left {
    flex-basis: 455px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.contact__form-right {
    flex-basis: 455px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.contact__form input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #999;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact__form p:nth-child(3) input {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


.contact__form textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" name="contactForm" class="contact__form">
  <div class="contact__form-wrap">
    <div class="contact__form-left">
      <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="your Name *"></p>
      <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your e-mail *"></p>
      <p><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact__form-right">
      <textarea name="text" id="contactText" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your message *"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="contact__btn-wrap">
    <button type="submit" class="contact__btn btn">Send Message</button>
  </p>
</form>
```